# Apache NiFi - getting multiple processor groups data synchronized to for single zip

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently using Apache NiFi. In it I have three components that get data. I need to generate one single ZIP file that contains all this data, but I have a problem that arises. Some of the components finish before other components meaning they get to the processor that zips files before all the other data does. when this happens I am left with multiple Zip files when I want to have a single Zip file.

A current solution that is implemented is leaving all the data in temporary storage on a server where we can then retrieve the data and zip all at once. The problem with this solution is that it requires a server to hold this data, is there a solution using only NiFi where we can get all of the data from these components at the same time to zip?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: MergeContent should work for you. Just add corresponding `fragment.*` attributes your flow files and merge content will wait for all required files to zip .

Comment: @daggett I thought that the fragment.* was specific to flowFiles that all originate from a single flowFile. Are you saying that you can use the fragment.* somehow to gather unrelated flowFiles?

Comment: flowfiles could be coming from anywhere you want. you have 3 subflows of data. 1st should set `fragment.count=3, fragment.index=0`, 2nd - `fragment.count=3, fragment.index=1`, 3rd - `fragment.count=3, fragment.index=2`. if waves of flow files are far from each other in time then `fragment.identifier` could be a constant for all 3 subflows. if next wave of files could come while first wave is processing - you need to find some value for `fragment.identifier` that is unique between waves but common for every three files you want to zip.